# Refactoring cucumber steps with similar steps

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to refactor a cucumber scenario that contains too many repeatable steps. I want to clean it up so that it is much easier/cleaner to read. Here is the scenario:

```
Feature: Sample Fruit Basket purchase
Scenario: Purchase a sample fruit basket after changing the fruits
  Given That I am on the sample fruit basket page
  When I add an apple
  And I add a banana
  And I add an orange
  And I remove a pear
  And I remove a plum
  And I add a strawberry
  And I add a straberry
  Then ....... 
  ....
```

Is there any way I can clean up the add/remove steps? I was thinking of a table but was not sure that was the way to do it or if it could be done with a table.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
Feature: Sample Fruit Basket purchase
Scenario: Purchase a sample fruit basket after changing the fruits
  Given That I am on the sample fruit basket page
  When I add fruits:
    |apple|
    |orange|
  And I remove fruits:
    |pear|
    |plum|
  And I add fruits:
    |strawberry|
  Then ....
```

Your step definitions might look like this (note the `I add fruits` step below)

```
Given(/^That I am on the sample fruit basket page$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When(/^I add fruits:$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When(/^I remove fruits:$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

**Updated for single table**

```
Feature: Sample Fruit Basket purchase
Scenario Outline: Purchase a sample fruit basket after changing the fruits
  Given That I am on the sample fruit basket page
  When I add <addfruit> 
  And I remove <removefruit>
  Then ...
  Examples:
    |addfruit|removefruit|
    |orange|apple|
    |pear|plum|
```

Comment: Thanks Bala. That will reduce the number of steps. Is there a way to use one table for both add and remove?

Comment: You can use one table with scenario outline. I have updated my answer.